# Update the page with the responseText for xmlHttprequest even the readyState is not equal to 4 for IE8 browser

Tags: responsetext

I need to update the page with the responseText even the readyState is not equal to 4.
I got the response to the browser but if i am trying to get the responseText, it is showing script error in IE older versions and chrome.
It is working fine in Firefox and IE10 browsers.
Can anyone help me to get responseText in IE older versions and chrome browsers.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText!="" && self.xmlHttpReq.readyState!=4){
   updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
}
self.xmlHttpReq.send(string);
```